# Page count for printed pages in .Net

Tags: .net, printing

I want to be able to put page numbers like "Page 1 of 7" on the pages I print from my application. Therefor I have implemented a two-pass printing routine. The first pass prints to a file and is automatically cancelled when I'm done. The total page count from the first pass is used in the second pass where I send the data to the printer.

Here is the code that generates the two types of PrintDocuments

```
 public static PrintDocument CreatePrintDocument(PrinterConfiguration printerConfig)
    {
        PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
        document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerConfig.PrinterName;
        document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = printerConfig.IsLandscape;
        document.PrintController = new StandardPrintController(); 
        return document;
    }

    public static PrintDocument CreatePrintDocumentThatCancelsPrint(PrinterConfiguration printerConfig)
    {
        PrintDocument document = CreatePrintDocument(printerConfig);
        document.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
        document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = CreateTempFileName();
        document.EndPrint += (sender, e) => { e.Cancel = true; };
        return document;
    }
```

The problem is that PrintToFile doesn't always work. On one Windows XP test computer I get a Win32Exception - Invalid handle when performing the first the pass. So after a bit of googling I found that setting PrintDocument.PrintToFile from code isn't supported.

> "The PrintToFile property is only used by the PrintDialog and cannot be set programmatically."
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printtofile.aspx

So, why not print directly to the printer and cancel it in the EndPrint event? Well, then the user will get the "Save as" question for both the first and the second pass if printing to the "XPS Document Writer" printer.

So the question is; How can I do a two pass print without seeing the "Save As" dialog twice when printing to the "XPS Document Writer"?

**RESOLUTION**

As JonB pointed out, I needed to look at the PreviewPrintController instead as that is a print controller that allows me to do silent interaction with the selected printer.

```
public static PrintDocument CreatePrintDocument(PrinterConfiguration printerConfig)
{
    PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
    document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerConfig.PrinterName;
    document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = printerConfig.IsLandscape;
    document.PrintController = new StandardPrintController(); 
    return document;
}

public static PrintDocument CreatePrintDocumentThatCancelsPrint(PrinterConfiguration printerConfig)
{
    PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
    document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerConfig.PrinterName;
    document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = printerConfig.IsLandscape;
    document.PrintController = new PreviewPrintController();        
    document.EndPrint += (sender, e) => { e.Cancel = true; };
    return document;
}
```

Comment: Try using the print preview dialog instead for the first pass (you can hide it if you like).

Comment: I'm afraid that the PrintPreviewDialog will give me another problem as we are trying to print from a service as well.

Note that the problem I have described occurs when running the application as a normal consol application.

Comment: @JonB After thinking about your comment for a while I realized that I can use the PreviewPrintController without actually using the actual preview viewer control. Tomorrow I will test to print using the PreviewPrintController instead of the StandardPrintController for the first print pass.